# Android 12 custom notification small icon background color (always white)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-notifications

Solved : Problem was in icon background color

Android custom notification's small icon has alway white background.  I tried different thing but could not get it work. I tried to use transparent icon.  Here is code:

```
       new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, COOK_CHANNEL_ID).
    setCustomContentView(presenter.getCollapsedViews())
    .setCustomBigContentView(presenter.getExpandedViews())
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_amazon_alexa)
        //              .setColor(Color.GREEN)
                        .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle());
```

Comment: is ic_amazon_alexa drawable an svg/xml?

Comment: yes it is, but i tried png as well same result

Comment: when using an svg/xml drawable, you can change the background color to transparent by using fillColor attribute `android:fillColor="@android:color/transparent"`

Comment: or do you need to set a specific background color programmatically?

Comment: @Lino thank you so much , that was my mistake issue was in icon background color. By mistake i tried two different icon both had issue . so now i created an other icon and it wok okay .thanks for help